# Getting all information from specific in a nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to grab a set of data from a nested dictionaries by looking at a specific key.

My nested dictionaries looks as follows:

```
dict_items = {
    "base_id": {
        "some-id-C03": {
            "index": 3, 
            "role": "admin", 
            "text": "test_A_02", 
            "data": {
                "comment": "A test", 
                "version": "1", 
                "created": "05/09/18 14:18", 
                "created_by": "John"
            }, 
            "type": "subTesting", 
        }, 
        "some-id-B01": {
            "index": 1, 
            "role": "admin", 
            "text": "test_B_02", 
            "data": {
                "comment": "B test",
                "version": "1", 
                "created": "05/09/18 14:16", 
                "created_by": "Pete"
            }, 
            "type": "subTesting", 
            "id": "33441122-b655-8877-ccddeeff88bb"
        },
        "some-id-A03": {
            "index": 1, 
            "role": "admin", 
            "text": "test_C_01", 
            "data": {
                "comment": "C test",
                "version": "1", 
                "created": "15/06/18 09:12", 
                "created_by": "Pete"
            }, 
            "type": "subTesting", 
            "id": "55667788-c122-8877-zzddff00bb11"
        }
    }
}
```

While I can perform using the following:

```
for item in dict_items.get('base_id').values():
    print item['data']['created_date']
```

How can I tell/ append the other information that belongs within the `created_date` that I have queried?

For example, I had wanted to grab the latest 2 information (using the `datetime` module), in this case, it will be returning me all the information that belongs to the key - `some-id-C03` and `some-id-B01`

This is the output I am expecting:

```
"some-id-C03": {
    "index": 3, 
    "role": "admin", 
    "text": "test_A_02", 
    "data": {
        "comment": "A test", 
        "version": "1", 
        "created": "05/09/18 14:18", 
        "created_by": "John"
    }, 
    "type": "subTesting", 
}, 
"some-id-B01": {
    "index": 1, 
    "role": "admin", 
    "text": "test_B_02", 
    "data": {
        "comment": "B test",
        "version": "1", 
        "created": "05/09/18 14:16", 
        "created_by": "Pete"
    }, 
    "type": "subTesting", 
    "id": "33441122-b655-8877-ccddeeff88bb"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you mean 'created' when you write 'created_date' ? And you could explain yourself better ? I don't understand what do you need. You need to append the information to the dict ?

Comment: appending other info where? can you show expected output

Comment: You have the information you need, if I understand, in the item variable, you can save the last two items ordered by the created field of the data field in the loop updating two auxiliar variables.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the lack of clarity. I have added what I am expecting to get, based on the derivation from `created` (Sorry I thought, I was using `created_date`). Currently while I can access the date, I am having issues with getting the expected output that I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can all values associated with the `"data"` key, and then sort based on the month:

```
import datetime, re
def _sort_key(d):
  return list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', list(i.values())[0]['data']['created'])))

def get_data(d):
  _c = [[{a:b}] if 'data' in b else get_data(b) for a, b in d.items() if isinstance(b, dict) or 'data' in b]
  return [i for b in _c for i in b]


results = sorted(get_data(dict_items), key=_sort_key)[:2]
```

Output:

```
[{'some-id-C03': {'index': 3, 'role': 'admin', 'text': 'test_A_02', 'data': {'comment': 'A test', 'version': '1', 'created': '05/09/18 14:18', 'created_by': 'John'}, 'type': 'subTesting'}}, {'some-id-B01': {'index': 1, 'role': 'admin', 'text': 'test_B_02', 'data': {'comment': 'B test', 'version': '1', 'created': '05/09/18 14:16', 'created_by': 'Pete'}, 'type': 'subTesting', 'id': '33441122-b655-8877-ccddeeff88bb'}}]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back! The output that you have placed here, is half of what I was looking for. I am trying to get the whole 'chunk' (I added that into my initial post)

Comment: Thank you. I have a question though, it seems that you hardcoded it to check the dates by the current month, but I am trying to get it, for example the latest 2 results (say, in my dict_items, all 3 items' created is the same date but different timing)

Comment: @TehKi In that case, you will have to sort your results. See my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to query this data structure such that you end up with all of the entries that match some criteria.

I'd set that up something like this:

```
def query_dict_items(data_dict, condition_fn):
    '''
    Return a list containing the contents of `data_dict` for which 
    `condition_fn` returns `True`.
    '''

    results = []
    for data_item in data_dict['base_id'].values():
        if condition_fn(data_item):
            results.append(data_item)

    return results
```

Then you can define whatever conditions you'd like. For the example of retrieving all items created on a certain date:

```
from datetime import datetime

#   Define a condition function that matches items from Sept 5th, 2018.
sept_5 = datetime.strptime('05/09/18', '%d/%m/%y')
def was_on_sept_5(data_item):
    date_str = data_item['data']['created'].split(' ')[0]
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%y').date() == sept_5.date()

#   Print the resulting list.
from pprint import pprint
pprint(query_dict_items(dict_items, was_on_sept_5))
```

Hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.